# apache beam global combine shuffle

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, shuffle, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

In my apache beam and dataflow pipelines , i do some transforms that need a global combine operation , like min , max , custom global combine functions.
The number of items to be processed in the pcollection is in order 2-4 billions.

I read that most combine operation are built on top of groupBykey , which causes a shuffle , which i believe makes my current pipeline slow or as observed from UI the highest wall time in the global combine operation. I looked into code and the groupByKey tries to add a static void key to all elements and then do a groupby , does this mean we are shuffling the data (specially when we just have one key) ? 
Are there ways to do this effeciently

Another question for my own understanding : beam/dataflow documentation says all elements of a key are to be handled by a single worker/thread. Taking example of finding a max in pcollection of integers, this global operation is completely parallelizeable where my combiner/accumulator work on partial/subset of data to find max and then merge the partial results (merging two max to get max), in a tree like structure  where results of leaves can be merged to get parent node and each node basically can be evaluated in a distributed manner. So what operation exactly enforces that one key has to be handled by one worker/thread. seems like any global operation where you have combiner that is commutative and associative can be easily parallelized. What part of the global combine needs to go through a single worker thread ?

Comment: I have observed that behaviour, and I am struggling with it. When you create a Combine.globally() only the methods createAccumulator, addInput and extractOutput get called. That means that threre was a shuffle and mergeAccumulators was not needed. I am trying to figure out the reason looking to the code but apache beam code is awful. For me makes sense to do a partial combine per bundle later partial merges and finally collect all. But that is not really what is happening so the doc is lying.

Answer (score 0):

The combiner will be lifted ahead of the shuffle (meaning we do some combining before passing to a shuffle). There's a little bit of information here: https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/02/writing-dataflow-pipelines-with-scalability-in-mind , search for combiner.

Dataflow will assign a distinct key to each element, so you will not end up with all the same keys (and therefore no parallelism). If it was all assigned to one key, then only one worker would be able to process and it would be very slow.

Comment: So basically any global combine operation will be too slow ?

Comment: even finding min and max will be too slow ? usually that doesnt happen

Comment: can you explain what you mean by distinct key to each element , the cource code shows it assigns the same void key to each element ? I ma very confused by what you said "so you will not end up with all the same keys (and therefore no parallelism)." seems like wrong to me, more keys mean more shuffle and more parallelism ?

Comment: I do not know what the code shows, but the result is not the same key on every element. Likely the void keys are replaced later on in the pipeline.

If every element had the same key, you would get no parallelism and it would be single threaded.

Global combine will have a shuffle but should not be too slow since some work is done prior to shuffle.

What do you mean 'usually that doens't happen'.

Comment: Ok reading beam/dataflow source code , we add None (python) and Void , keys for every element. This aligns with what i observe when i look at the number of workers autoscaled . In my global combine operation , the number of workers are scaled down to 1 . Another question is , why do you need a shuffle for global combine , why do you need to shuffle data at all when you have one single key , what is the rationale behind it ?

Comment: just to be clear , when i say key , i am talking about Pcollection of elements being converted to Pcollection of keyvalue pairs of key-elements by a createKey Map transform , and not some internal unique key for caching and handling distributed system failures

Comment: The pipeline needs to distribute its workload across all workers. In order to do so, you add a shuffle step where each element will be assigned a distinct key and, according to that key, you can allocate it to different workers. Each worker will handle elements within a key range and, if the shuffle is not skewed, they will all process a similar load.